# How to alter my css less code without !important

Tags: css, nested, less

I have something like this:

```
table {
thead {
    th{
        background-color: @grey-1;
        ...
    }
}
position: relative;
&.option1 {
    thead {
        th {
            background - color: @grey-2;
            ...
        }
    }
} 
&.option2 {
    thead {
        th {
           background - color: @grey-3;
           ...
        }
    }
}
&.option3 {
    thead {
        th {
            background - color: @grey-4;
            ...
        }
    }
}}
```

I have another class to insert:

```
.clean {background-color: transparent;}
```

And my point is to make this table to have a transparent th background:

```
<table class = "option1 clean"> </table>
```

Briefly, I need to alter my less file by inserting .clean class so that "table .option1 .clean" would have a transparent background. It has to be done without inserting .clean into every .optionX class and adding !important.

Any options?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Just add a rule for `.clean` below the options (under `table`, not inside each individual option):

```
table {
    &.optionX {
        ...
    }

    &.clean {
        thead {
            th {
                background-color: transparent;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thought of that, but isn't it the only option? Imagine there's a huge less file with 200 optionX classes :(

Comment: You don't need to put it inside each option. Just make this the last rule under `table { }`

Comment: Kind of strange behavior of less, but that worked. THX!

Comment: Nothing strange about it, it's how css works. The last rule of the same strength applies over the previous ones.